# Django Restframework FileUpload with Angular

Tags: django, angularjs, curl, file-upload

for hours I have been trying to get a FileUpload working with DRF and Angular. I have a view like this:

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, pk):
         print request.FILES
         #do something
         return Response(status=204)
```

and I am using angular-file-upload (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) like this (The getCookie() Function comes from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)) :

```
var csrf = getCookie('csrftoken'); 

    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        queueLimit:1,
        url:'upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf
        }
    });
```

However, when I send data to the url using curl it works:

```
curl -X POST \
    --dump-header - \
    -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
    -u admin:admin \
    -F "image=@/Users/magda/test.pdf;type=application/pdf" \
http://localhost:8000/lectures/166/upload
```

But whenever I use the angular function I get:

```
detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

I also tried to add csrf_exempt to the function, which did not change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error as you using angular-file-upload.  I just scraped the csrf token and included it in my data so django would allow it.

```
$scope.$watch('files', function() {
      if($scope.files) {
          var csrf = $cookies.csrftoken;
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
              var file = $scope.files[i];
              $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                  url: '/api/v1/attachments/',
                  data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf, message: 6 },
                  file: file // single file or a list of files. list is only for html5
              }).progress(function (evt) {
                  console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total) + '% file :' + evt.config.file.name);
              }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // file is uploaded successfully
                  console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + data);
                  data.filename = config.file.name;
                  $scope.attachedFiles.push(data);
              }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('fail to upload ' + config.file.name + ' -  response: ' + data.details);
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, I had to add the csrftoken to formdata and not to the header.

Answer (score 0):

Your key for CRSF token might have been incorrect, Here is how I did it (still working out the `onBeforeUploadItem()` part):

#### App.js

```
require('angular-file-upload');

angular.module('app', [
    'angularFileUpload'
])
```

#### Controller

```
function controller(FileUploader, $q, $cookies, logger) {
    var vm = this;

    function activate() {
        vm.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: '/api/expense-claim/' + vm.expense.id + '/transport-cost-attachment/',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get('csrftoken')
            }
        });
        vm.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = onBeforeUploadItem;
    }

    function onBeforeUploadItem(fileItem) {
        fileItem.formData.push({creator: vm.owner});
        fileItem.formData.push({attachment_file: fileItem.file.name});
    }

    activate();
}
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="vm.uploader"/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.uploader.queue">
        Name: <span ng-bind="item.file.name"></span><br/>
        <button ng-click="item.upload()">upload</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```